# Switching off the automatic insertion of links and Wikipedia references in Writer

Tags: formatting, openoffice, openoffice-writer

Whenever I try and insert pure text into OpenOffice.org Writer it replaces the text with Wikipedia links and references.

I can't find where I to switch of this annoying feature. (I have already switched 'AutoCorrect - URL Recognition' off)

See the picture below:

[image: autocorrect dialog in OpenOffice.org Writer]

Answer (score 2):

From the screenshot, you don't actually have "pure text" but instead are pasting in content from a webpage.

When you cut and paste from a website into most word processors, you carry over the HTML formatting with links and all that.

If you paste directly, you'll see all the links appear in the document.

To cut and paste without all those links or formatting go do the following when you're in the document (after having already selected and copied the text to the clipboard):

> Edit > Paste Special... > Unformatted text

This will drop in just the text you've selected.